# Need a python authentication / authorization framework

Tags: python, security, authentication, authorization

I'm writing a web application that requires authentication / authorization. That is, this web app will allow users to log into the site and gain access to material not accessible to anonymous users. Unfortunately, Flask does not come with a built in authentication / authorization system. Experts highly discourage rolling out a custom system, so I don't want to do this. Is there a good, full-fledged authentication / authorization framework that I can use for my application?

Comment: Full fledged web framework: https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: I've definitely considered it. I really like the minimalist approach of Flask though. Do you think that Flask's lack of authentication / authorization system is a good enough reason to just drop it and go with a full stack framework?

Comment: There is no "right answer" to this question. Your polling people for recommendationns, so your questions isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [**Flask-Auth**](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Auth/).

Answer (score 0):

[Fedora Account System](https://fedorahosted.org/fas/) is an extensible JSON-based authnz provider. [python-fedora](https://fedorahosted.org/python-fedora/) is a module that provides FAS auth plugins for a few web frameworks as well as raw Python modules for communication with it.